# rxjs: any "joining" alternative to withLatestFrom operator?

Tags: rxjs

```
observable1.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(observable2),
  .. do something with both emitted observable values
)
```

Problem with `withLatestFrom` is that if `observable2` hasn't emitted any event before the `observable1` did then it's a dead code. How should I modify the code to ensure that `do something with both emitted observable values` will have have both observable values emitted at least once prior to the call? Maybe some wrapper around the `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the RxJS [`combineLatestWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith) if you're looking for a pipable operator instead of `combineLatest` function.

```js
observable1.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(observable2),
  // ... do something with both emitted observable values
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a use case for the [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) operator. This operator takes an array of observables and waits for every to emit at least once. Once all the observables have emitted, the operator emits for the first time. After that it emits every time any of the observables emits.

Comment: combineLatest is not a pipable operator ( similar to forkJoin )

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce a first emission with `startWith()`, you apply it to both observable 1 and 2 depends on your need.

```
observable1.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(observable2.startWith(null)),
  .. do something with both emitted observable values
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I however need a real first emission from the observable2, the mockup approach won't work in my case.

Comment: without startWith the behaviour of combineLatest is very similar with your current approach in your use case, they will only emit if both source observable emits.

Answer (score 0):

NgRx provides a [`concatLatestFrom`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/12.4.0/modules/effects/src/concat_latest_from.ts) operator implementation you can reference. It wraps `withLatestFrom` to produce the behavior that you (and very many others) are expecting and is potentially more semantically clear than `combineLatestWith`. This also works on versions RxJS before 7:

```
source1$.pipe(
  concatLatestFrom(source2$),
  ...
)
```